# How to solve the error when deploying a smart contract in Ethereum?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, ethereum, solidity

When trying to compile the smart contract with solc-js I was getting the error

Krishna:Voting krishnakankipati$ node deploy.js
 Compiling the contract 
 assert.js:350 
     throw err; ^
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid callback specified.

```
let compilerInput = {
     'Voter': fs.readFileSync('Voter.sol', 'utf8')
};

console.log('Compiling the contract')
// Compile and optimize the contract
let compiledContract = solc.compile(compilerInput, 1);

// Get compiled contract
let contract = compiledContract.contracts['Voter:Voter'] // Voter contract from Voter file.

 // Save contract's ABI
let abi = contract.interface;
fs.writeFileSync('abi.json', abi);
```

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to deploy your smart contract so I could assist?

Comment: @BenBeck. Sure Sir.

Comment: @BenBeck. This is my GitHub link please take a look at it Sir. https://github.com/Krishna2709/Voting-SmartContract/blob/master/deploy.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be sure to read the [solc docs](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js) for solc v0.5.0+ to ensure you're adjusting for the changes to the Solidity compiler.

Something like this should be compatible  with the latest version of solc:

```
// Note: You should be defining your contract sources as objects now.
// Note: You must also provide the compiler output selection as well.
const compilerInput = {
    language: "Solidity",
    sources: {
        'Voter': { content: fs.readFileSync('Voter.sol', 'utf8') }
    },
    settings: {
      outputSelection: {
        "*": {
          "*": [ "abi", "evm.bytecode" ]
        }
      }
    }
};

console.log('Compiling the contract')
// Note: You have to pass the input in with JSON.stringify now.
const compiledContract = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(compilerInput)));

if(compiledContract.errors) {
    compiledContract.errors.forEach(err => console.log(err.formattedMessage));
}

// Note: This changed slightly since I'm using JSON.parse above.
const contract = compiledContract.contracts['Voter'].Voter; // Voter contract from Voter file.

// Note: This is now called 'abi' and not 'interface'
const abi = contract.abi;
fs.writeFileSync('abi.json', JSON.stringify(abi, null, 2));
```

You'll also need to update your `deployContract` function to be in sync with solc v0.5.0+

```
async function deployContract(web3, contract, sender) {
    let Voter = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(abi)));
    let bytecode = '0x' + contract.evm.bytecode.object;
    let gasEstimate = await web3.eth.estimateGas({data: bytecode});

    // The rest should work fine...
}
```

Comment: It was working when I have installed again...using the command                                   > npm install solc@0.4.25 --save

Comment: @Krishna0727, right, the code you had works with solc <= 0.4.29. The code I've provided works with solc >= 0.5.0 which is what you initially had declared in your `package.json`.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1                  > const compiledContract = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(compilerInput)));

Comment: @Krishna0727, could you post a new script to your GitHub where you attempt use the above code?

Comment: https://github.com/Krishna2709/Voting-SmartContract/blob/master/deploy.js

Comment: @Krishna0727, I'm not able to reproduce this error using solc@0.5.2. Please ensure you are using solc@0.5.2 as your `package.json` shows, if you're unsure what version you're using, delete your `node_modules` folder and re-run `npm install`.

Comment: I was getting this error   at line 37       TypeError: Cannot read property 'Voter' of undefined

Comment: @Krishna0727, then you have issues with your smart contract and your smart contract does not match what you have checked into your repository. See my updated code and add the lines to log compiler errors to see what issues you have with your smart contract.

Comment: Sir the contract was compiled but it failed to deploy.

Comment: krishnakankipati$ node deploy.js
Compiling the contract
Failed to deploy contract: ${error}

Comment: Sir, the error is saying that it was failed to deploy the smart contract since abi wasn't defined.

Comment: Sir the problem is with the smart contract code. I have done a small mistake in the contract code. Now the contract is executing well.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using solc-js correctly. You need to stringify the input, and you're passing a 1 instead of an import callback. Please read the docs before posting questions: https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js

Consider using etherjs, much better documentation and more robust than web3.

Comment: solcjs isn't working when compiling the smart contract. And even the solidity docs says it isn't compatible with Geth.

Comment: Yes, because you're not using it correctly. Put the code in Remix and it will compile fine. What isn't compatible with geth?